# Query Results and display data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need help in creating a stored procedure that pulls out multiple data from different tables.

My current stored procedure is as follows:

```
  '@partnername nvarchar(120)
    as
select ProjectDetails.Project, ProjectDetails.Id
from ProjectDetails  
join ProjectPartners on ProjectPartners.ProjectDetailsId = ProjectDetails.Id
join Partners on Partners.Id = ProjectPartners.PartnersId
where Partners.PartnerName= @partnerName'
```

This Stored procedure allows a user to insert a partner name, this then displays the projects they are linked within.

But now I'm wishing to display more data within the stored procedure from other tables such as the following:
Table (ProjectFinance) columns ID, ProjectValue, FundingAgency and AgencyValue
Table (Partnership) Columns ID, PartnershipLevel, PartnershipType.

The Tables are linked using foreign keys within the project finance table & Partnership table these Foreign Keys are known as ProjectDetailsID

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the tables to your joins and add their columns to your select list:

```
select ProjectDetails.Project, ProjectDetails.Id, pf.*, p.*
from ProjectDetails  
join ProjectPartners on ProjectPartners.ProjectDetailsId = ProjectDetails.Id
join Partners on Partners.Id = ProjectPartners.PartnersId
join ProjectFinanct pf on pf.ProjectDetailsId = ProjectDetails.ID
join Partnership p on p.ProjectDetails.ID = ProjectDetails.ID
where Partners.PartnerName= @partnerName'
```